# Ajax, PHP, MySQL returning sql table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following Ajax code to send information from an HTML form to a PHP file.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#txt').load( '../../do_comment.php' );
     });
     $(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#user_name").val();
            var comment = $("#user_comment").val();
            var ID = '2'; //must change for each post
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../do_comment.php",
            data: {user_name:name, user_comment:comment, ID:ID},
            success: function(){
                $('#txt').load( '../../do_comment.php' );
            },
            error:function(e){alert("it failed");}
            });
        }); 
});
```

In my PHP file I declare the variables like this:

```
$name = $_POST[user_name];
$comment = $_POST[user_comment];
$ID = $_POST[ID];
```

And correctly populate my database with this:

```
 if($_POST[user_comment] != Null) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (post_ID, user_name, comments)
    VALUES ('$ID','$name', '$comment')";

    $result = @mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

 }
```

The problem is none of the variables will echo any sort of value, and when I try to query the database it only works if I hard code the ID value in instead of using the variable.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE post_ID = 
 '".mysql_real_escape_string($ID)."'") or
    die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: In your $_POST invocations you should do $_POST['user_name']; instead of $_POST[user_name]; Notice the quotes.

Comment: Also, don't user mysql_query. Use PDO. Search PDO php and use it.

Comment: You should include in your post what is it your getting echoed back

Comment: that variables will echo back nothing, meaning they must be null. But if they are null, how come they are populating the database properly?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following when gathering from $_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST:

```
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$comment = $_POST['user_comment'];
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
```

Notice the tics. Proper syntax is `$_POST['']`.

Have you checked the database to make sure the proper values are being inserted?

Also, if the `post_id` is an integer, don't use tics

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_ID = 1234
```

**NOTICE**: do not use MySQL_*, it has been deprecated in PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi or PDO. Watch out for SQL injections as well, especially when using MySQL_*.

Comment: I added the tics into the declaration. No luck. My database is being filled with the proper values, which is why this does not make sense to me. Also if I do not use tics around the variable name in the select statement when using a variable, I receive an error.

Comment: what's your error? Integers do not use tics and may cause the query to return nothing

Comment: also, try `echo $data;` and see how the query was built

Comment: I can hardcode the integers in with no error. But when I try to use the ID variable with the select statement I receive a syntax error.

Comment: when I echo $data I get Resource id #4

Comment: sorry. Try `$query =...` then `echo $query;`. So we see the string built. So use the string in the `mysql_query()` to set `$query`

Comment: the post_Id is returning a null value. But how can it be null if it is populating the database?

Comment: do you have `auto_increment` set on the column?

Comment: no I dont have auto_increment set, the ID should either be either a 1 or a 2

Comment: not sure what to tell you now other than check your queries/insert commands (echo them out) and escape your values, since you missed it for the insert too. You can try to echo out the value and then echo the escaped value.

Comment: Is your column `post_id` a `varchar` or `int`? Also, is the insert and query in the same page ie. run insert then grab it?

Comment: the post_id column is a varchar, and yes the insert and grab is on the same page.

Comment: Ok, tics are needed for `varchar` (hence my if statement in my answer). This is strange. Is there any code in between the insert and query that could override the `$ID`? (I noticed your question from 2 days ago)

Comment: even if I echo the ID before the insert it returns a null value, but somehow the insert still populates the table correctly.